# What is the behaviour in Jersey if I have two equal paths but one has a parameter?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I would like to know what happen if I have two `@PUT` services in Jersey and one is defined as:

```
@PUT
@Path("/{elementId}")
```

And another one as:

```
@PUT
@Path("/service")
```

What is the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given all else is the same (i.e. content negotiating annotations and such), given what you have provided, if you access the `/service` path, the explicit `@Path("/service")` will always be hit.

In the matching algorithm<sup>**[1]**</sup>, the primary key in sorting the candidate methods, is the number of literal characters in the path expression. `@Path("/service")` has more (the other has none), so it will always win. You should easily be able to test this behavior.

**[1]:** See [3.7.2 Request Matching (in the JAX-RS spec](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec.html). The part that specifies the above is 2.f (the same is detailed about the class level `@Path` annotation, in 1.e)